# Wordpress Script and styles plugin include script option

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to include script to in individual wordpress individual page, but include script is disabled and can't write into the richtextbox don't know why, check the snapshot attached !

[image: scripts included snapshot !]

Comment: Please see this on how to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This screen shot is not part of WordPress by default. It's probably part of your theme. The WP way to add js is [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and for css [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

For theme specifics I recommend asking the theme author/support.